# What does inet_pton do? Shouldn't I get my IP address but in decimal?

Tags: c++, networking

```
std::string ipv4address("192.168.255.18"); 
struct in_addr ipSourceAddress;
inet_pton(AF_INET, ipv4address.c_str(), (void *)&ipSourceAddress);
std::cout << "ipSourceAddress.s_addr: " << ipSourceAddress.s_addr;
```

I get

```
ipSourceAddress.s_addr: 318744768
```

However any [online converter](https://www.ipvoid.com/ip-to-decimal/) gives me `3232300818` which is the value that works on my IP crafter.

Why I get different values?

Comment: In C++, please don't put `struct` before a type in a variable declaration. It is redundant in C++ (contrary to C) and may cause issues if name lookup for the type fails, because rather than generating an error, it will declare a new `struct` of that name in sometimes surprising scopes. The cast `(void *)` is also redundant and it is generally a good idea not to use casts if not necessary and to use the weakest cast necessary, i.e. here (if it wasn't redundant) `static_cast<void*>(&ipSourceAddress)` to avoid accidental wrong casts that could cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inet_pton` (and `struct in_addr` in general) stores the result in *network byte order*, i.e. big endian. Print both values in hex and you'll immediately see that. To get it back to a meaningful integer, run it though `ntohl`.